# Table inside div goes out of div in Chrome only. It works fine in all other browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a div which have a fixed width then a table inside which is width:auto and the table has 2 column.  I tried many things like 100%.  The only working solution is to have the input search at 150px I don't understand.

The table goes out of the div as shown in this jsfiddle :

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;border-radius:15px;margin-left:10px;float:left;width:180px;height:26px">
    <table border="0" style="width:auto;height:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <img id="SearchIcon" src="/Content/icons-png/search-white.png" width="16" height="16" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:4px;margin-right:5px">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="SearchBox" type="search" style="border:1px solid red;border-radius:0 12px 12px 0;height:100%;width:auto" placeholder="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/840ngzzL)

Comment: The 100% I changed was not at the right place.  I was suppose to change it on the input as Hitesh mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `width` in your `input`

```
width:auto;
```

to

```
width:100%;
```

That will do it.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The input element has a by default size. Which can vary according to the browser.
So you have to give width to the input element so that it can be overridden.

Put `width:100%` in you input element and it will work.

So your code will like this

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;border-radius:15px;margin-left:10px;float:left;width:180px;height:26px">
    <table border="0" style="width:auto;height:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <img id="SearchIcon" src="/Content/icons-png/search-white.png" width="16" height="16" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:4px;margin-right:5px">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="SearchBox" type="search" style="border:1px solid red;border-radius:0 12px 12px 0;height:100%;width:100%" placeholder="Search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```